# How to teach and document intuition and experience?

Tags: colleagues, mentoring

A part of my role as a technical team lead in cybersecurity team at my workplace is to mentor more junior security engineers. While other job roles may have hard rules to follow that  almost always apply, such is not the case in IT security. We have best practices but implementation and analysis of adequacy requires intuition and experience that only comes with work experience. I have been working in cybersecurity for slightly more than 6 years and they about 2 years.

As an example, when performing pen tests, reviewing pen test findings or granting security sign off on a user story, there really isn't a set of hard rules that if met signifies one of our  products is secure or not met, insecure. One must understand risk management, threat landscape, and also draw from past breaches. How such factors weigh will also be different from product to product.

In my guidance documentation, I don't want to handhold junior team members by being excessively prescriptive of what they should or should not be reviewing in each use case as I believe such approach hurts employee development and because IT security is a very dynamic field.

However, junior team members have given me feedback that they find my mentorship and guidance too theoretical without enough concrete details. I have been getting increasing requests from them to list very specific , prescriptive points to review in scans of products, something I am very reluctant to do.

**How do I help more junior team members improve their intuition and "feel" for IT security without spoon-feeding them every fine detail?**

Comment: What you think is "spoon-feeding" may actually just be good mentorship and training. Just because you may have learned your skills by a sink-or-swim approach doesn't mean that everyone has to do it that way. Work is not like stack-overflow, nor does it have to be a Calvinistic gauntlet where people must prove they are worthy of information. Maybe try a different approach? How about the good old socratic method? Ask pointed questions of your mentees, show them how you approach problems and get them to engage critically in what you're teaching them. Give it time and exercise patience.

Comment: Experience, by definition, is outside that which is taught. But you *can* teach the lessons of your experience and that of others -- it is through practice and the occasional failure that this will be synthesized into sound professional judgment. Also, some people learn well with "handholding", others don't. People who work with computers, esp. in the generation coming out of the 80's and 90's, are often very independent, but there is a price to be paid for that too.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I haven't worked in cybersecurity but I know the "how to teach intuition?" quandary very well from other areas of IT and from Audit. The trouble with "teach them how to determine if the product is secure without using rules" is that as stated, that really just boils down to a (higher-level) additional set of rules, ultimately. So you identify something that is a potential threat or risk: what do you do? (cont)

Comment: (cont...) Well, for example, maybe the answer in that specific case is "check the process downstream of it for errors" (or whatever applies). But that isn't a general rule, as in you can't write a process that says (e.g.) "if X seems fishy then check the process downstream of it for errors", as that won't be applicable in different-but-seemingly-similar situations.  It's an interesting discussion -- I've always thought that intuition is something 'other' than just the synthesis of experience and rules. My partner in a similar field is adamant that there's no 'intuition', just experience!

Comment: Potentially related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/140031/handing-off-to-another-team-support-processes-how-to-communicate-that-not-ev/140034

Comment: @Seventyeightist , exactly! As someone who began in forensic accounting and internal audit, sometimes it's the unconscious factor thats important. Being able to read between the lines and discern the unsaid from the data that one does have. I see your 4 wing speaking now as someone who is 6 with 5 :)

Comment: If it were possible to somehow "document intuition" I daresay our whole educational system would look vastly different than it does today. Documentation has limits. You (OP) seem to agree with this in a comment below, where you state that some things cannot be spelled out - so it would help to know how much you are looking for an answer about how to write documentation specifically, vs. an answer about just "how can I help my team members" (as you word it in your final sentence), which obviously goes beyond just documentation.

Comment: You may inevitably have to be specific and prescriptive at the outset, so that they can examine how ends meet and try and infer the connections and principles. "Intuition" is sometimes a byword for the tacit knowledge that comes about from having observed a prodigious number of specific examples over a significant period of time, but which has not been reduced to communicable knowledge of concepts, or a stepwise procedure. And this style of operation will inevitably have high reproduction costs, so that *most* of your working time may be spent reproducing a small team with your same skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I help more junior team members improve their intuition and "feel" for IT security without spoon-feeding them every fine detail?

Do the tasks together and coach by asking open questions rather than telling them what decision to make.

> As an example, when performing pen tests, reviewing pen test findings or granting security sign off on a user story, there really isn't a set of hard rules that if met signifies one of our products is secure or not met, insecure. One must understand risk management, threat landscape, and also draw from past breaches. How such factors weigh will also be different from product to product.

What works for me is to teach such an "expert decision" tasks is to do the review together and let the mentee do all the work, with me in the background asking questions.

- "What is your impression of this pen test?"
- "What threats are being is discussed?"
- "How does the tested product deal with scenario X?"
- "What do you think about these results?"
- "What is your final verdict then?"

Ask the questions you would ask yourself, but don't answer them yourselves. Only step in, when the mentee draws the wrong conclusion, or even better let them figure out by themselves by asking more leading questions.

When it comes to conclusions be open minded and accept verdicts you wouldn't have necessarily found yourself. E.g. if you have to decide whether to approve or reject a test report and would go for "reject", but it is a close enough call that "accept" would be reasonable too, then don't correct your mentee if they go for "accept", as long as their reasoning is substantiated and they not missing anything.

If you keep doing these discussions, you will find some things you will have to explain over and over again. These are the items you would want to capture in a written documentation, to save you some time.

Comment: This raises a good point about nuance that is often missed. Often there can be a number of different valid responses to an issue. And it comes down to providing sound rationale. (It's why I don't like intuition, because you can't provide rationale, and thus you can't explain why you arrive at a particular response.)

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia defines intuition as "the ability to acquire knowledge without recourse to conscious reasoning."

Professionals should always be looking to convert their sub-conscious reasoning, into conscious reasoning, evaluate and understand the reasoning, and document it for others.

Structural engineers don't rely on intuition. When looking at building plans, there are models they use to determine if a building is safe. If their intuition leads them to find something that wouldn't be found, they update their models to ensure its checked in the future.

Pilots don't rely on intuition. When there is an emergency, they go through a checklist. If the checklist doesn't pick something up, the airplane manufacturer will update the checklist.

This doesn't mean that intuition serves no purpose. Intuition may help you find things quicker, and more efficiently. It also you finds gaps in your documentation.

> One must understand risk management, threat landscape, and also draw from past breaches. How such factors weigh will also be different from product to product.

Why is it not possible to document these things so that CAN be understood? You're relying on a lot of implied knowledge, which is impossible for them to know. So ensure the knowledge is not implied, but documented. This also helps ensure it is correct.

It also helps validate the modelling that your more senior members do.

Comment: You answer is very counter-intuitive (no pun intended), but it makes a lot of sense not to have to rely on intuition.

Comment: _Pilots don't rely on intuition. When there is an emergency, they go through a checklist._ There was an interesting counter-example to this in the movie about the Sully ditch landing (not sure if this specific scene was based on real events!) in which in the following inquiry they asked Sully about what calculations he performed in order to determine that he couldn't make it to an alternate airport and would have to ditch on the Hudson instead? And his answer was that he "eyeballed" it, he didn't make any explicit calculations... that's prima facie 'intuition'.

Comment: _If the checklist doesn't pick something up, the airplane manufacturer will update the checklist._ Yes, no doubt they will -- but in the meantime, faced with a situation for which there is no checklist or where they have tried the checklist but it failed or couldn't be applied for some reason... the pilot still has to do 'something' in the moment, presumably something off-script. You could say they use their experience to decide what's the best thing to do even if it's not in the manuals, and I expect that is the case, but at least in some cases there's still the 'unconscious' factor.

Comment: @seventyeightist I did say further in my answer that intuition helps us fill gaps and work faster.

Comment: Overwhelmingly, a building which was regarded as structurally sound in the 80s or 90s is still structurally sound today. Now, think about how much Infosec has changed in that time. Social engineering was barely considered, there was no 2FA, no-one thought about XSS, one "secure" password was the gold standard. This is a very fast moving domain. Some specific checks can be taught and documented, sure, but teaching someone "how to fish" (i.e. how to stay up-to-date) is maybe more valuable here.

Comment: @JoeStevens Best practices are not intuition. A fast moving field is no excuse to not try to understand what underpins our subconscious thoughts and document those to help others. I'm saying factors that underpin specific products should be documented. And yes, there should be test plans for specific products. The field isn't moving so fast that people have to "wing it" every time.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Maybe a better analogy is medicine. Medical treatments advance constantly, all the time, recommended drugs change, recommended doses change, and so on. Specific knowledge has a short shelf-life, and there is little value in one doctor writing his second-hand point-in-time knowledge for the benefit of another. Instead, sources of knowledge are documented. How to keep up to date is documented. But junior colleagues can't expect to be spoon-fed every single thing. A certain amount of initiative is needed.

Comment: @JoeStevens I am not saying junior colleagues should be spoon-feed every single thing. I'm saying the knowledge that the seniors know should be documented, and the juniors should be able to make up their on decisions. In addition, I'm saying any decision making processes made by the seniors should attempt to be rationally understood, and not just chalked down to "intuition". Juniors should be able to understand how decisions are made by senior people and not just have a magic word called "intuition" be invoked, and call it a day.

Answer (score 2):

Training is best done in detail with a manual for reference. You cannot teach intuition, and it is not how cyber security works. Your method is not intuition, it's years of details being put together, nothing esoteric about it, most professional fields are the same.

You need to go to basics and do the details and work your way up. If products differ you go through the whole process again specific to the product.

When details change, you update the manual.

If it's not done like this the company risks multiple potential points of failure. The idea behind proper manuals is that any suitably qualified person can follow instructions and familiarise themselves with everything while performing the necessary tasks.

Comment: Kind of concerning when something so important has to rely on intuition and experience. Or at least when someone in a position of leadership thinks that is the case.

Comment: @Gregory Currie what I mean by intuition is that sometimes you need to get the "feel" and make a decision based on information that may not be complete, and obtaining complete information is not feasible. Sometimes knowing what's important to test is not, and cannot be, spelled out prescriptively

Answer (score 2):

> In my guidance documentation, I don't want to handhold junior team
> members by being excessively prescriptive of what they should or
> should not be reviewing in each use case as I believe such approach
> hurts employee development and because IT security is a very dynamic
> field.

Don't write the guidance documentation all by yourself. Do it on a wiki. Assign your juniors a couple of sub-topics. Do a couple of sub-topics yourself first to set the tone and the overall structure.

If they've overlooked something, you can fill in the gaps. And if you've overlooked something, maybe they can help fill in the gaps also. The point being. If you put them in charge of trying to teach others a particular topic, there is no better way to learn it themself. See the Richard Feynman [learning technique](https://fs.blog/2021/02/feynman-learning-technique/).

Do the same if you're having a meeting about this. Instead of having a single person present to others and have everyone else remain passive. Have a roundtable discussion and have one or two people scribe, or have everyone prepare and present a subtopic for 2 to 5 minutes

Answer (score 2):

How about Case Studies?

You walk them through every step of your thinking and testing for a given scenario. What factors you weighed, decisions you made, and your eventual analysis.

This allows you to give them the details they’re asking for while also (hopefully) making it clear that there is no one size fits all approach to what you’re doing.

Added bonus:

Write down 2 or 3 of these and you’ll probably see a lot of repeated steps. Congratulations! You’ve just found some concrete details and considerations that your juniors can look out for in their future reviews.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been getting increasing requests from them to list very specific , prescriptive points to review in scans of products, something I am very reluctant to do.
>
> How do I help more junior team members improve their intuition and "feel" for IT security without spoon-feeding them every fine detail?

**Alternate between spoon-fed/specific details and your current, more theoretical guidance.**

If they feel you are too theoretical, then try now and then dropping some specific insight or points to review in scans (i.e., showcasing a bit your know-how, intuition, and experience).

Usually, at first you *may* want to "spoon-feed" a bit more, and then as they progress the spoon-feeding will be needed less and less, as they develop their own intuition/experience.

Answer (score 1):

Let's restructure the question into the two key questions:

1. How do we teach intuition or intuitive thinking?
2. How do we document experience?

Both are very doable but at different levels of detail.

Intuition is a macro or bigger picture thing which we can really sum up as culture. The need for I.T. to create a culture around security and safety needs to be at the forefront of the company culture. We can teach this through behavior modification techniques:

- Create easy to remember advice / guidelines (e.g. "Too good to be true = it is", "Slow down and think before acting", "Question everything, do not blindly trust anyone", "Ask the I.T. help desk or a manager via a known phone number or email", "Don't click links without carefully inspecting them", "Don't give information out willingly especially personal or private information. When in doubt, it's private and a secret", etc.)
- Create routine internal tests (e.g. Send phishing email tests, Do regular audits, explore physical device security [people leaving devices unlocked], etc.)
- Require routine and continuous training (e.g. self-paced training on I.T. threats, continuous simulations of various incident types and/or events, external testing [hire firms dedicated to testing their ability to breach your security ... keep it on a need to know basis] and auditing, automatic (re)training on people who fail internal I.T. tests, etc.)
- Send routine reminders and examples of "Do not do..." or "Do the following..." which are "tips & tricks" style company wide memos/emails
- Remove individuals from sensitive positions who exhibit problems with maintaining I.T. standards and security
- Conveying a spirit of "***You* ARE the first line of defense** to stopping problems and disasters before they come crisis and failures" with *EVERY* employee from the CEO to the janitor is of the utmost importance ... but ***when something does go wrong*** and that first line of defense fails: having excellent backup systems and the sense "***Contact I.T. immediately*** as time is of the essence in containing and correcting the problem(s)."
- Cultivate a thirst within the team for constant improvement and research of the latest technology trends, cybersecurity threats, and best solutions/strategies for mitigating those threats (e.g. reading credible articles/books/blogs/etc., visiting cybersecurity oriented websites/forums/conferences/etc., and diving into the I.T. world from all angles [esp. ethical hacking ... learning how it's done to prevent it happening in your company]).

Documenting experience is a micro level concern where individual incidents or cases need to be logged in a documentation system (e.g. knowledge base, FAQ, and/or Wiki) that is a S.P.O.T (Single Point Of Truth). Whatever system is used needs to be easy to use both from a "file it" perspective and a "retrieve it" perspective. Good search tools, categorization, and organization are essential to providing a solid documentation system that will be used, maintained, and updated.

Whenever there is a failure or incident, the entire incident *must* be logged in the system. Everything should be covered from a "Step-by-step breakdown of what happened by all actors" to "What did we do right" / "What did we do wrong" and "How did we fix the problem/enhance the security of the company" point of view. There should be an investigation in all cases that ultimately leads to this documentation getting created and appropriate new policies, procedures, and practices being put into effect immediately.

Establishing standard operating procedures (e.g. checklists and policies) for disasters, breaches, and other I.T. critical events (incl. termination of employees/contractors/etc., transferring users, absorbing new business units/companies, etc.) should also be put in this system (with great detail). All checklists and associated reference materials (e.g. system manuals, accounts, shared credentials, servers, etc.) should be placed here as well. A good book on checklists is "[The Checklist Manifesto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0312430000)".

Creating routine processes that update and ensure the information in the system is accurate, current, and clear is just as essential as well (doing this around the holidays when there is a low volume of work is a great idea). Also, creating routine audits of the system are essential to test it functions as intended and is improved in the areas where it is lacking (e.g. information is not easily found or categorized, an incident is not logged, the correct procedures is no used, the system is not consulted for an incident, there are enhancements needed for specific cases). A knowledge base system is only as good as it is current, clear, and correct.

This is the kind of approach used (and even enhanced) in the most successful companies and I.T. focused teams/organizations. Regularly consulting external resources such as Microsoft best practices/feedback, Deloitte/I.T. professional consulting firms, and government agencies feedback/regulations is always a great step ensuring you, your team, your I.T. department, and your company are staying ahead of the latest threats and risks in the I.T. realm.

Best of luck! :)